# VPC networking connection on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vpc, google-suggest, google-vpc

Let me brief out question agian:
Let say their are 3 VPC network (default)VPC1,VPC2.VPC3
1. VPC1 have two subets 10.128.0.0/20& 10.10.1.0/24
2. VPC2 subnets: 192.168.0.0/24
3. VPC3 subnets:10.10.2.0/24

Created 2 VM's instances:
VM1 assigned two interface : ETH0(10.128.0.0 IP) & ETH1(192.168.0.0 IP)
VM2 assigned two interface : ETH0(10.10.1.0 IP) & ETH1 (10.10.2.0 IP)
VPC peering is already done between  VPC1(default) & VPC3  as my VPN tunnel is established to communicate with my remote data centre.(It's working perfectly as all iproute & firewall has been set)

Need to connect ETH1 network "10.10.2.0 & 192.168.1.0"

Comment: Why the question is marked with "-1" ,if it not clear/understandable ,please let me know .  I need to trouble shoot this .

Comment: I am guessing because your question is a mess. You are using terms without details. Try rewriting your question, specify network, subnet and IP addresses. Then specify how you want to connect service and what problems you have connecting services together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below solution done:

1. Firewall rule created to allow traffic between VPC2 "192.168.1.0" and VPC3 "10.10.2.0" and checked
2. VPC peering has been created between VPC2 "192.168.1.0" and VPC3 "10.10.2.0" and checked
3. Ip route has been written between them VPC2 "192.168.1.0" and VPC3 "10.10.2.0"

Comment: Please let me know ,why the answer is not useful.  practically i had implemented it

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have 3 networks, and you want VM's to be able to communicate with each other even if they are in different network (and also in different subnets).

Make sure your networks' address ranges don't overlap (fe. 10.0.0.0/24, 10.0.1.0/24 etc.). If they do you can't make peering connection between them.

Go to the [VPC Network](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/networking/networks/) and check IP ranges.

Then go to [VPC network peering](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/networking/peering) and make a connection (you have to have at least two for each connection; one from VPC1 to VPC2 and second from VPC2 to VPC1 in order to connection to be active (if it's not it means you just have one-sided connection).

If you want three networks to communicate you have to have connections 1>2,1>3,2>1,2>3,3>1,3>2.

When you have a connection active (between networks you want) then check firewall rules if they don't block the traffic - add proper rules if necessary.

If you've done all of this then ping any machine from VPC2 from any in VPC1 or VPC3 and it should work.

**There's one if**. Do you have two interfaces in the VM in question ? If so check if the IP routes are configured properly for the second interface (let's call it ETH1) - if they're not then you won't be able to talk to the network assigned to ETH1. Check the documentation for [configuring proper routing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#configuring_policy_routing).

Comment: Thanks , more over i got idea through your answer.

Comment: I had revised the question ,can you go through it